# FOSUserBundle is querying twice to get the User

Tags: mongodb, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, monolog

Check out lines #2 and #3 starting from bottom:

```
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] request.INFO: Matched route "myapp_main_default_index" (parameters: "_controller": "Myapp\MainBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "myapp_main_default_index") [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"find":true,"query":{"_id":{"$id":"504f548c8c2d892617000000"}},"fields":[],"db":"myapp_db","collection":"User"} [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"limit":true,"limitNum":1,"query":{"_id":{"$id":"504f548c8c2d892617000000"}},"fields":[]} [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"limit":true,"limitNum":1,"query":{"_id":{"$id":"504f548c8c2d892617000000"}},"fields":[]} [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
[2012-09-11 16:44:55] security.DEBUG: Username "test" was reloaded from user provider. [] {"token":"504f6a8727898"}
```

Seems to me like it's making a duplicate query.

What should I do?

Comment: that's hard to track down without provided code..
Most IDE's support debugging with xDebug, you could follow each line beeing executed.

PHPStorm, Eclipse.. choose your weapons and track this down :)

Comment: You could enable the MongoDB [profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) at a level of 2 (all queries) to confirm if there are actually double queries, or if this is just a logging anomaly.  I'm not familiar with FOSUserBundle, but it's possible that it does do multiple (duplicate) queries as part of its logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think it's not querying more than once, it's just how it logs. In other queries, there is 1 log line for each part of the query, but the dev toolbar shows it as 1 query, so it must be right.